# Swap partition does not mount on restart

Tags: hibernate, fstab, swap

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and was trying to enable Hibernate.I came across that one should have Swap Partition equivalent to RAM in system so created one.
My file system information on

`sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000b11e9

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63       96389       48163+  de  Dell Utility
/dev/sda2           98304    84097023    41999360   83  Linux
/dev/sda3        84097024   167878655    41890816    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       167879311   312575999    72348344+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       167879313   287396152    59758420    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       287397888   310425599    11513856    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda7       310427648   312575999     1074176   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

I am able to hibernate my system once I swapon my /dev/sda7 partition.

For that I do,
`mkswap /dev/sda7` 
and `swapon /dev/sda7`

I even added entry in /etc/fstab

`UUID="xxx" /dev/sda7 none swap sw 0 0`

Everything happens successfully including `sudo pm-hibernate`
But when I restart my system after Hibernate its not able to load my swap partition.

I checked using Gparted Partition Editor then for /dev/sda7 the file system becomes unknown.
Please help in resolving this.

Answer (score 3):

Is that the actual line you have in fstab for the swap partition? If it is replace "xxx" with the real UUID. You can get that by running

```
 sudo blkid
```

My swap line is

```
UUID=2188134d-a147-4db9-9b58-fe12f7b74a58 none swap sw 0 0
```

my blkid output

```
/dev/sda2: UUID="72cf9e50-f555-476e-a018-cec87a86d2bb" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="2188134d-a147-4db9-9b58-fe12f7b74a58" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="14143c21-08e9-4d31-b083-f6efb11234fb" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda7: LABEL="1210" UUID="955bd082-58af-46fc-a72b-016c9d7a3150" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="14ee47cc-54cb-4887-8773-fd53121efe10" TYPE="ext4"
```

Backup and edit the fstab file to change as necessary

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak && gksudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

It might also be worth checking that the UUID in /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume is correct.

```
cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
```

This should match the UUID for the swap partition, if it is different then change the UUID

```
sudo cp /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume.bak && gksudo gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
```

Comment: `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` is not there in my file system.

Should I create any file inside `conf.d`?
Regarding UUID,it matches the blkid.So,no problem there.Do you need any other info.

Comment: You could create the resume file all you need us RESUME=UUID=yourswapuuid     Is your swap encrypted? Might make a difference

Comment: I noticed one more thing that when I reboot my system post Hibernation,
`sudo blkid`
gives me:
`/dev/sda7: UUID="48194385-9cdd-464f-8df7-73322d9db5a4" TYPE="swsuspend"`
I don't know why its type is changed here.Is it creating problem??

Comment: still my problem is not resolved..someone please guide me

Comment: not sure what the suspendsw is about - try removing it and recreating it - check the blkid in both the fstab and resume files afterwards again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do

```
sudo update-initramfs
```

after changing it.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You may want to add additional information so that the original poster knows what he's doing when typing those lines of code into the terminal.